# Any workaround to manipulate NERs (named entity recognition) as new columns in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

I have celebirty news dataset and I can extract name entity recognition from those. Initially, I figured out how to get continuous NER (named entity recognition) from a list of sentences with `nltk` tool. Now I want to split NER by subject, location and main topic and add them as new column. Here is what I tried:

```
from nltk import ne_chunk, pos_tag, word_tokenize
from nltk.tree import Tree

import nltk
nltk.download('maxent_ne_chunker')
nltk.download('words')

def get_continuous_chunks(text):
    chunked = ne_chunk(pos_tag(word_tokenize(text)))
    continuous_chunk = []
    current_chunk = []
    for i in chunked:
        if type(i) == Tree:
            current_chunk.append(" ".join([token for token, pos in i.leaves()]))
        elif current_chunk:
            named_entity = " ".join(current_chunk)
            if named_entity not in continuous_chunk:
                continuous_chunk.append(named_entity)
                current_chunk = []
            else:
                continue
    return continuous_chunk
```

here is the output of above helper function:

```
res=[]
for x in df.sentences:
    ner=get_continuous_chunks(x)
    res.append(ner)
```

> [['Jennifer Aniston', 'ITV', 'NBC', 'Aniston'],  ['Brangelina',
>   'Brad Pitt',   'Angelina Jolie',   'Brad',   'Friends',   'Jennifer
>   Aniston',   'Brad Jen',   'Ange',   'Jen',   'Brangelina Brad',   'Jen
>   Brad',   'Angelina'],  ['Jennifer Aniston', 'US', 'Aniston', 'New York
>   Post', 'InTouch'],  ['Jennifer Aniston', 'Mexico'],  ['Jennifer
>   Aniston', 'Friends', 'Matt LeBlanc', 'Star', 'Paul', 'Jennifer'], 
>   ['Jennifer Aniston',   'Justin Theroux',   'Marie Claire',
>   'Aniston',   'Huffington Post'],  ['Jennifer Aniston',   'Justin
>   Theroux',   'Star Magazine',   'Jennifer Aniston Jennifer Aniston',
>   'Brad Pitt',   'Brad Pitt Jennifer Aniston',   'Angelina Jolie',
>   'Jennifer']]

**update: current output snippet**:

here is current output snippet, I want to extract `person`, `location` and other `event` and add them as a new column to original dataframe. Here is what I got:

[image]

now I want to further extract out name of person with `TFIDF` and `news_source` such as `New York Post`, `Star Magazine` or similar typer as new column. I don't know how to get this done. Any thoughts to make this happen?

**desired output**:

basically, I want to reshape the output of continuous NER by a person, location, source as new columns in dataframe. Here is my example output:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'sentence':['longtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtext', 'longtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtext', 'longtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtext' ],'celebretity_name': ['Jennifer Aniston','Brad Pitt','Jennifer Aniston'], 'source':['NBC','Friends','New York Post']})
```

can anyone point me out how to get this done? is that possible to split extracted NER by `celebrity name`, `news_source` as new column in dataframe? any thoughts? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

It'll be slow but this should work:

```
df['celebretity_name'] = df.sentences.apply(get_continuous_chunks)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is that possible to extract `PER`, `GPE`, `ORG`, `EVE` from extracted chunked NERs and add them as new columns to dataframe? Do you have any thoughts? Thank you very much